# 3D Gauss-Hermite Quadrature

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, quadrature, numerical-calculus

Is it possible to examine a 3D integral by using Gauss-Hermite quadrature type technique? I mean there might be an equation like this (with analogy to 1D Gauss-Hermite quadrature):

$\int_{-1}^{-1} \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-1}^{1} f(x,y,z) dx dy dz = \sum_{i} \sum_{j}\sum_{k} w_{ijk} f(i,j,k)$

I appreciate your help and suggestions!

Comment: May be applying it to each integral? See http://math2.uncc.edu/~shaodeng/TEACHING/math5172/Lectures/Lect_15.PDF

Answer (score 1):

Just looking the boundaries of your integral, I wouldn't use Gauss-Hermite. I would use Gauss-Chebyshev or Gauss-Legendre depending on the function $f$. You should just apply the quadrature formula with the order of integration.